# Integrating mathJax in my angular project

Tags: angular, angular-material, mathjax

I have been trying to integrate mathjax in my angular project, Using [this GitHub code](https://github.com/shubhvjain/angular-mathjax) and there is just one problem which is using mathjax component from my other component and not directly from the main app component. I can't share the full code here but I'll share the error and the things I already tried and that's not working.

Error: `ERROR in Can't bind to 'content' since it isn't a known property of 'mathjax'. ("rol" rows="3"style="resize: none; height: 100px">
<mathjax [ERROR ->][content]='questionList[currIndex].problemText' class="box">
")
'mathjax' is not a known element:

1. If 'mathjax' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. To allow any element add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("form-control" rows="3"style="resize: none; height: 100px">`

Things I tried:

- Adding NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA to my NgModule schema
- importing mathjax component in my other app component and define it in directives(which gives an error)
- add NgModule to my other app component with declarations of mathjax but that also doesn't help.

If you need more information to give answers please ask I'll reply instantly, I am a bit out of time now.
Any help would be really appreciated.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass your data using the `innerHTML` property of a div in your mathjax component.

```
<div id="mathContent" [innerHTML]="content"></div>
```

From https://github.com/shubhvjain/angular-mathjax/blob/master/src/app/mathjax/mathjax.component.html

Comment: Yes I tried that like this: `<app-mathjax [content]='questionList[currIndex].problemText' class="box"></app-mathjax>`  But this doesn't seem to help it because the error says it can't recognize app-mathjax and I need to declare it first which I already did.

Comment: You have 2 separate problems here:
1) MathJaxComponent is not declared in the module that consumes it. So you should add it to the `declarations` array in the module.
2) Angular thinks you are passing `content` as a property (using `@Input content`) to that `<app-mathjax>` component which is probably just a regular component. If you don't have that variable defined as an input for that component, Angular is going to throw an error.

`<div id="mathContent" [innerHTML]="questionList[currIndex].problemText' class="box"></div>` 

What is in your <app-mathjax> component?